# How to enumerate PGP keyring e-mails related to a specific ccTLD

Tags: email, gnupg, pgp, enumeration, host-discovery

I would like to enumerate all possible PGP e-mails related to [North Korean top-level domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.kp) `.kp`

Few years ago I would have used [theHarvester](https://github.com/laramies/theHarvester) but I recently discovered that this useful tool doesn't support PGP keyring search any more :(

If I use the official [MIT PGP Key Server search](https://pgp.mit.edu/) and I try to search for `.it`:

[image]

the search starts but it then ends up in an error:

[image]

Which makes sense, there are maybe too many entries.

But for North Korea it might maybe be possible because they had only [1024 routable IP addresses](https://www.trendmicro.com/en_us/research/17/j/a-closer-look-at-north-koreas-internet.html), the [list of website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_North_Korean_websites_banned_in_South_Korea) is not that long, and I'm quite sure some might have used PGP. Or maybe not?

Anyway, do you know any tool alternative to theHarvester to dig into e-mails by top-level domain?

Comment: its open source.... you could add the code needed for your specific usecase...

Comment: @LvB I don't think so. If the author removed the PGP feature is because it was no more compatible. In fact the MIT Key Server doesn't provide API endpoints so the only alternative would be to write a web crawler. But that web crawler will be kicked off like in the screenshot. That's why I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: What's your goal here? Blocking all mail from `.kr` is pretty simple, but scraping a list of PGP keys that claim to sign `.kr` domains is much more complicated and I'm not sure how useful it is. Also recall that there's no mandate anywhere within PGP usage for a key to actually be added to key servers. For secrecy or privacy, many users intentionally avoid public PGP servers. I expect that to be more common in North Korea.

Comment: Thank you @AdamKatz, I just want to try to send an e-mail to North Korea. In order to do that I need to enumerate as much e-mail address as possible. Any tool or advice that will help me enumerate e-mails will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A keyserver can't let users query something that will return arbitrarily large amounts of data. If this were possible it would make them extremely vulnerable to Denial of Service.

If you want to find all keys containing emails in a certain domain, you'll have to download the SKS keydumps (for example, from [here](https://keys.niif.hu/keydump/)) and trawl through them.

The keydumps total around 11 GB, so this is no small project.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!!!